# Suggest me some ideas on Text input using react dot notation

Tags: reactjs, input, components, textinput

How do write a text input component using react dot notation?

Ex. I want to access it like this in a functional component.

```
<TextInput.Label></TextInput.Label>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should do something like:

```
import React from 'react';

const TextInput = ({children}) => {
  return (
      <div>
        {children}
        <input />
      </div>
  );
};

TextInput.Label = () => <p>Label</p>

export default TextInput;
```

Usage would be like:

```
<TextInput>
  <TextInput.Label />
</TextInput>
```

**Edit**:

For adding prefix and suffix:

```
import React from 'react';

const TextInput = ({children}) => {
  return (
      <div>
        {children}
        <input />
      </div>
  );
};

TextInput.Label = ({prefix, suffix}) => {
  return(
    <>
      <p>{prefix}</p>
      <p>Label</p>
      <p>{suffix}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default TextInput;
```

Usage:

```
<TextInput>
   <TextInput.Label prefix="prefix" suffix="suffix" />
</TextInput>
```

Comment: What if I wanna add a prefix or suffix inside a input field?

Comment: @Sowmya I updated the answer above. If you found it correct please accept the answer!

Comment: I wanna append suffix or prepend prefix to the input not to the label.

Comment: Ok simply pass prefix and suffix to the input component:

<TextInput prefix="prefix" suffix="suffix">
   <TextInput.Label  />
</TextInput>

Comment: @Sowmya and 

const TextInput = ({prefix, suffix }) => {
  return (
      <div>
        {children}
        <input />
      </div>
  );
};

Comment: @Sowmya BTW it's better to ask all your questions once. This saves the community's time and also your time!